# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in MdDataTable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, get, angular-material

I'm using MdDataTable to display some data that I want to retrieve from server. I want to use pagination.
This is the **angular** code:

```
    $scope.paginatorCallback = function(page, pageSize){
        var offset = (page-1) * pageSize;

        MySrv.getData.get(
            {
                offset: offset,
                pageSize: pageSize
            }, function (data) {
                return {                  
                        results: data.list,
                        totalResultCount: data.totalResults
                    }
            }, function (error) {
               alert(error);
            }
        )
    }
```

This is the **html** code:

```
 <mdt-table
    paginated-rows="{isEnabled: true, rowsPerPageValues: [5,10,20,50]}"
    mdt-row-paginator="paginatorCallback(page, pageSize)"
    mdt-row-paginator-error-message="Error happened during loading nutritions."
    mdt-row="{
        'table-row-id-key': 'fields.item_id',
        'column-keys': [
            'fields.item_name',
            'fields.nf_calories',
            'fields.nf_total_fat',
            'fields.nf_total_carbohydrate',
            'fields.nf_protein',
            'fields.nf_sodium',
            'fields.nf_calcium_dv',
            'fields.nf_iron_dv'
        ],
    }">
    <mdt-header-row>
        <mdt-column align-rule="left">Dessert (100g serving)</mdt-column>
        <mdt-column align-rule="right">Calories</mdt-column>
        <mdt-column align-rule="right">Fat (g)</mdt-column>
        <mdt-column align-rule="right">Carbs (g)</mdt-column>
        <mdt-column align-rule="right">Protein (g)</mdt-column>
        <mdt-column align-rule="right">Sodium (mg)</mdt-column>
        <mdt-column align-rule="right">Calcium (%)</mdt-column>
        <mdt-column align-rule="right">Iron (%)</mdt-column>
    </mdt-header-row>
</mdt-table>
```

It call the server and retrieve data correctly (so it is not a problem of the server), but I can't see any data in the html and I have this error in console:

```
angular.js:13708 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at mdtAjaxPaginationHelper.fetchPage (http://localhost/vendor/mdDataTable/md-data-table.js:629:17)
at new mdtAjaxPaginationHelper (http://localhost/vendor/mdDataTable/md-data-table.js:586:18)
at Object.getInstance (http://localhost/vendor/mdDataTable/md-data-table.js:677:24)
at initTableStorageServiceAndBindMethods (http://localhost/vendor/mdDataTable/md-data-table.js:208:85)
at new mdtTableController (http://localhost/vendor/mdDataTable/md-data-table.js:197:17)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost/vendor/angular/angular.js:4709:19)
at $controllerInit (http://localhost/vendor/angular/angular.js:10234:34)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/vendor/angular/angular.js:9147:34)
at http://localhost/vendor/angular/angular.js:9553:13
at processQueue (http://localhost/vendor/angular/angular.js:16170:28) undefined
```

Comment: `MySrv.getData.get` looks like it is asynchronous and you are returning from it?

Comment: yes it is async... but if I remove the return, do I have to write 'this.result' and 'this.totalResultCount'?

Comment: so make it sync with promise or q and you will have the then function

Comment: How can I convert it?